# Copy an Object into an other with 2 different variables

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, copy-constructor

I have the following problem.
I have 2 Webservices let us call them WebService1 and WebService2. Both of them contains a Object "WebServiceObject".
The WebServiceObject contains round about 60 variables. 58 are the same but 2 are different.
Is there any other way to copy the WebService1.WebServiceObject into WebService2.WebServiceObject without building a Copy-Constructor and assign variable to variable?

Comment: You could achive this with AutoMapper. Have a look at http://automapper.org/

Comment: Nice Tool!. I've done it this time manually but i installed it now. Thanks!